# Arranged in ascending order excluding one item

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table

[image]

Here I want to arranged table in ascending order order by firstname and those who are from UK by customer id. I tried doing this

```
select *
from tblCustomers
order by FirstName, LastName, age asc
where not country = 'uk'
```

but we can't do it as where clause should be used after table name and when we do

```
select *
from tblCustomers
where not country = 'uk'
order by FirstName, LastName, age asc
```

It exclude UK which is not my desired solution. How can I arranged in ascending order, order by firstname and firstname from UK from customer Id?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Its not clear what you desired results are... how do you want to order the customer from the UK?

Comment: And you say "excluding one item" but there are 2 from the UK. And then you say "It exclude UK which is not my desired solution" so you do want to exclude them and you don't want to exclude them? Very hard to know what you are looking for.

Comment: @DaleK I want to order uk one by customer Id

Comment: Use `CASE` expression? As mentioned, your question doesn't make much sense, and you seem to understand what the `WHERE` does; it filters the data that would be returned, it has nothing to do with the order of the data returned.

Comment: You realise that storing age is a bad thing to do? It changes every year...

Comment: And the columns you show in your image are different to the columns in your query.

Comment: [Conditional ORDER BY](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/conditional-order-by)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build the `order by` clause up using case expressions e.g.

```
declare @tblCustomers table (customer_id int, first_name varchar(12), last_name varchar(12), age int, country varchar(3));

insert into @tblCustomers (customer_id, first_name, last_name, age, country)
values
(1, 'John', 'Doe', 31, 'USA'),
(2, 'Robert', 'Luna', 22, 'USA'),
(3, 'David', 'Robinson', 22, 'UK'),
(4, 'John', 'Reinhardt', 25, 'UK'),
(5, 'Betty', 'Doe', 28, 'UAE');

select *
from @tblCustomers
order by
    case when country = 'UK' then 1 else 0 end asc -- non-UK first
    , case when country = 'UK' then customer_id else null end asc -- UK ordered by id
    , first_name, last_name, age asc; -- Non-UK ordered as specified
```

Returns:

| customer_id | first_name | last_name | age | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Betty | Doe | 28 | UAE |
| 1 | John | Doe | 31 | USA |
| 2 | Robert | Luna | 22 | USA |
| 3 | David | Robinson | 22 | UK |
| 4 | John | Reinhardt | 25 | UK |

Notes:

- please don't use images as we can't copy and paste the data
- ideally provide the DDL+DML (as I have shown) as this makes it much easier to answer
- always ensure your question is consistent, with the same table and columns names throughout
- always provide your desired results
- don't store age in a database, store date of birth and calculate age.